# How to convert this PostgreSQL in Laravel Query Builder without using DB::Raw

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to transform a PostGreSQL Query in Laravel Query Builder Syntax, but isn't working

```
SELECT users.*, rifs.rif
FROM users
JOIN rif_user on users.id = rif_user.user_id
JOIN rifs ON rifs.id = rif_user.rif_id
WHERE email = 'email@email.com';


$busq = DB::table(['users','rifs'])
->select('rifs.nombre','users.email','rifs.rif')
->join('rif_user','users.id', '=', 'rif_user.user_id')
->join('rifs', 'rifs.id', '=', 'rif_user.rif_id')
->where('email' ,'email@email.com')
->get();
```

I Try the code on Laravel Tinker and there is the Output:

> > > ->select('rifs.nombre','users.email','rifs.rif')
> > > PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on line 1
> > > ->join('rif_user','users.id', '=', 'rif_user.user_id')
> > > PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on line 1
> > > ->join('rifs', 'rifs.id', '=', 'rif_user.rif_id')
> > > PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on line 1
> > > ->where('email' ,'email@email.com')
> > > PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on line 1
> > > ->get();

Comment: Hi Reinaldo, "Isn't working" isn't very descriptive.  Please use the [edit] link and add either what error you are getting, or what the expected result vs actual result you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an alias for each table, like this

```
$busq = DB::table('users as u')
->select('r.nombre','u.email','r.rif')
->join('rif_user as ru','u.id', '=', 'ru.user_id')
->join('rifs as r', 'r.id', '=', 'ru.rif_id')
->where('u.email' ,'email@email.com')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

$busq = DB::table('users','rifs')->select('rifs.nombre','users.email','rifs.rif')->join('rif_user','users.id', '=', 'rif_user.user_id')->join('rifs', 'rifs.id', '=', 'rif_user.rif_id')->where('email' ,'email@email.com')->get();

i done it puting all code in a single line